# iPhone - stdint.h file not found!

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am dealing with a project designed for iPhone OS 2.0 and I am intending to keep compatibility with this version while offering new OS 3.x functionality.

When I set the base SDK to iPhone OS 3.1.3 and Target OS for 2.0, Xcode gives me this error during compilation.

**'stdint.h'** file not found
/Developer/usr/lib/clang/1.0.1/include/stdint.h:32:16: fatal error: 'stdint.h' file not found

The strange thing is that the file is there, on the path it says it is not.

if I set the target OS for 3.x the problem vanishes.

how to solver that?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use Clang LLVM to compile your iPhone project.  That is not supported at the current time for iPhone applications, only GCC is.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but where do I check this? As far as I know I have done nothing to change the compiler from gcc...

Comment: Under the build settings for your project and target, look for the "C/C++ Compiler Version" setting and make sure it says GCC 4.2, not LLVM GCC 4.2 or Clang LLVM 1.0.